# HE gas furnace replaced bad inducer but no ignition

Tags: furnace

I have an approx 20-year old Tempstar (model # NUGK125DK08, manufactured by 'Inter-City Products') 90% eff gas-fired furnace. Yesterday morning we noticed it was blowing only cold air. I opened it up and noticed a faint burning smell and poked around and noticed the inducer motor was hot and was not running when the furnace was switched on. I got the part today and replaced the inducer unit, which is running fine now when the furnace is switched on, but there is no ignition. What to check next?

Edit: @Mazura was right - it was the pressure switch. Note- in my previous comments, I mistakenly thought the heat switch mounted right on the inducer assembly housing was a pressure switch.

Comment: Check voltage to the igniter next.

Comment: Checked any of your limit switches? Listed for the gas valves to open or close, watch for ignition spark or glow.

Comment: What is the current ignition sequence?  If there's a limit that's not in the correct position (opened/closed), if could just be causing the inducer to run continuously (purging).

Comment: Do you have the model number?

Comment: Yes; edited to put the model up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressure switch on the inducer has to be satisfied before it will light the ignitor. If it can never verify that the inducer is blowing, it might run it forever and burn it out.

Comment: Agreed.  Check to make sure the pressure switch is closing as it should, and that all other switches are making/breaking as they should.

Comment: Definitely check everything else. I didn't look up this particular unit, but "just blowing cold" is indicative of a plenum over heat sensor gone bad (or doing it's job). And a continuously running inducer is the 'error code' for units that are old enough.

Comment: Thank you for the help- I turned it on with 1)one wire disconnected from the pressure switch- blower ran, inducer did not; 2)both wires disconnected from pressure switch and connected directly to each other- both blower and inducer ran. In both cases, there was no heating up of ignitor and no gas smell.

Comment: My last comment was referring to the pressure switch mounted directly on the inducer fan blade housing, btw. Next I'll check the fan and limit switch - sorry I am a novice and this is a slow process for me- I don't seem to have a heat sensor or a thermocouple but above I do have a honeywell fan limit switch - does this seem like a good thing to focus on next?

Comment: @hotkarl - continue to check sensors but add the model number to your post. If it has a HSI see if it's cracked or broken. If it has spark ignition, I'm only familiar with that on hot WHs, which usually means new control board/gas valve.

Comment: @Mazura- thanks- I edited to include model number. Seems to have Honeywell fan and limit switch, which doesn't seem to have any physical cracks or problems. But it seems like these can get gunked up and should be pulled out and cleaned periodically(?). The furnace has spark ignition; when it is properly starting up the ignitor will spark and light the pilot, which will then light the burners (I have another, slightly smaller, one on 2nd floor, same age, which is working fine).